# Difficulty in Writing a code for 3 arrays objects

Tags: reactjs

*I have 3 files, each file contains an array with objects, and each object contains several parameters, like in the example:*

*player.js*

```
const player = [
{playername:'1', teamname:['1','2',...], eventname:['1','2',...]},
{playername:'2', teamname:['1','3',...], eventname:['1','4',...]}
...
]
```

*team.js*

```
const team = [
{teamname:'1', playername:['1','3'...], eventname:['2','3'...], imageteam1:''},
{teamname:'3', playername:['1','4'...], eventname:['2','4'...], imageteam3:''}
...
]
```

*event.js*

```
const enent = [
{eventname:'1', playername:['1','3'...], teamname:['2','3'...]},
{eventname:'4', playername:['1','4'...], teamname:['2','4'...]}
...
]
```

*GridPlayerTeamsMembership .js*

```
class GridPlayerTeamsMembership extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;


return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List>
          {players.playerTeams.map(value => (
            <ListItem  dense button className={classes.listItem}>
              <Avatar src='' />
              <ListItemText primary={` ${value}`} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm editing the question to be clear where I'm having difficulties:
My purpose is to retrieve a specific property from a matching object in an array.

in the example above i got a list of teams , i want inside the  to retrieve the image that stored in object that represent that same team

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Assael! Please include the code you have written so far in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first what I would do to save some calculation time for each lookup, is to save those array into objects.

ie:

```
// instead of
const players = [
    {playername: 1, ....},
    {playername: 'key', ....},
];

// I'll have:
const players = {
    1: {playername: 1, ....},
    key: {playername: 'key', ....},
};
```

if you get it from some storage, you can easily convert the array to the mapped object with a loop.

```
const mappedPlayers = {};
players.map(player => {
    mappedPlayers[player.playerName] = player;
})
```

Now you do that for events and for teams.

After you have done that you can easily access specific team, player or event by its name (I prefer id, but as for this example its name)

Comment: please comment back for help or approved this so others could benefit